# R caret: rfe nnet "undefined columns selected"

Tags: r, r-caret, nnet

I am running into problems when applying recursive feature selection to `nnet` models with `caret::rfe`; I get the following error message:

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "undefined columns selected"

The actual task is more complex than the following example, but I am confident that this is a similar problem:

```
library(caret)

rfe(x = iris[,1:3],
         y = iris[,4]/max(iris[,4]),
         sizes = c(2), 
         method="nnet",
         rfeControl = rfeControl(functions = caretFuncs) 
         )
```

I know this error can occur when trying to select more features than there are available in x (e.g. see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18362/odd-error-with-caret-function-rfe), but this does not seem to be the problem here. I also ran very similar calls in earlier versions of caret, without this problem occurring.

I use R 3.3.1 and caret 6.0.71.

Thank you very much for your help.

EDIT: I went through the archived versions of caret and found that the example code is working in caret versions <= 6.0.62.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the archived versions of caret and found that the example code is working in caret versions <= 6.0.62. This also solves the problems my original code had. I reported this issue on the caret github.

EDIT: The problem is now fixed : https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/485